# Java Concurrency in Practice “Listing 7.15. Adding reliable cancellation to LogWriter.”. What is the point of loggerThread.interrupt()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading Java Concurrency in Practice and encounter the following code snippet (*Listing 7.15. Adding reliable cancellation to LogWriter.*).

```
public class LogService {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private final LoggerThread loggerThread;
    private final PrintWriter writer;
    @GuardedBy("this") private boolean isShutdown;
    @GuardedBy("this") private int reservations;
    public void start() { loggerThread.start(); }
    public void stop() {
        synchronized (this) { isShutdown = true; }
        loggerThread.interrupt();
    }
    public void log(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (isShutdown)
                throw new IllegalStateException(...);
            ++reservations;
        }
        queue.put(msg);
    }
    private class LoggerThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (LogService.this) {
                            if (isShutdown && reservations == 0)
                                break;
                        }
                        String msg = queue.take();
                        synchronized (LogService.this) {
                            --reservations;
                        }
                        writer.println(msg);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* retry */ } // interruption policy
                }
            } finally {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`LogService` is used to implement **"multiple-log-producer, single-log-consumer"** (multiple threads can execute `log(String msg)` task in order to put log into `queue`, one `loggerThread` can consume the log in `queue`).

But the `LoggerThread` has defined its own **interruption policy**, which is **"do nothing"** in the catch block. So, **what's the point of calling `loggerThread.interrupt();`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the loop:

```java
while (true) {
    try {
        synchronized (LogService.this) {
            if (isShutdown && reservations == 0)
                break;
        }
        String msg = queue.take();
        synchronized (LogService.this) {
            --reservations;
        }
        writer.println(msg);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* retry */ } // interruption policy
}
```

We see it has the following behavior:

- The thread blocks in `queue.take()`, waiting for incoming messages.
- It loops as long as the `LogService` has not been shutdown or there are still messages to log.
- Upon shutdown, if there's still messages in the queue they will be logged before the loop terminates.
- If the thread is somehow interrupted without the `LogService` having been shutdown then the thread continues on as if nothing changed. This prevents erroneous interrupts from breaking the service.

There's nothing to do in the `catch` block as the code to break out of the loop is handled elsewhere in the loop. If you wanted, you could have:

```java
catch (InterruptedException ex) {
  synchronized (LogService.this) {
    if (isShutdown && reservations == 0) break;
  }
}
```

But that would be duplicated, redundant code for no reason. We also don't want an unconditional `break` in the `catch` block because we want to loop until all messages have been logged, even after a shutdown; again, you could put that logic in the `catch` block but why do that when the rest of the loop already does the exact same thing.

And we need the call to `loggerThread.interrupt()` because the thread might be blocked in the `queue.take()` call. The interrupt wakes up the thread allowing it to check the break-out-of-loop condition. Without the interrupt the thread could remain blocked and never die.

Comment: "This setup" == "do nothing in the catch block"? If yes, it would be better to make it more clear.

Comment: It's not just the do-nothing-in-catch-block, it's the entire loop.

Comment: I edited my answer, trying to focus more on the empty `catch` block. Does it help?

Comment: I think `loggerThread.interrupt()` is used to prevent one specific situation, but not all `queue.take` blocking calls. That one specific situation is "when `loggerThread` executes `if (isShutdown && reservations == 0)`, it sees that `isShutdown` is false and reservations is 0, but before it calls `queue.take()` which will make it blocked, `stop` is call by someone". If `loggerThread.interrupt()` is not in the block, `loggerThread` will ramain blocked forever.

Comment: It's a little of both actually. If the service is shutdown just before the call to `take()`, but just after the check of `isShutdown`, the call to `take()` will immediately throw an `InteruptedException`. However, that scenario requires—in my opinion—unlikely timing; it's more likely the thread will be blocked in the call to `take()`. But it doesn't matter because the effect is the same.

Comment: There are other situations that can make `loggerThread` blocked in `queue.take()`. 1. `isShutdown` is true, `reservations` > 0 2. `isShutdown` is false, `reservations` > 0. But we don't need to worry that `loggerThread` remains blocked forever, because finally someone will put one item in the `queue` to let `loggerThread` exit block state. Do I understand it right?

Comment: Replied in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205268/discussion-between-jason-law-and-slaw).